# Plotting a discrete (or discontinuous) function in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following function, which I would like to plot using ggplot:

f(x) = 3/4 for x between 0 and 1; 1/4 for x between 2 and 3; and 0 elsewhere.

I have come up with the following R code:

```
eq<-function(x) {
    if(x>=0 && x<=1) {
        y<-3/4
    } else if(x>=2 && x<=3) {
        y<-1/4
    } else {
    y<-0
    }
return(y)
}

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-5,5)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun=eq)
```

However, this results in a plot with only a horizontal line centered on 0. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function should be "vectorized", i.e., 
accept a vector as argument.

```
eq <- function(x) 
  ifelse( x>=0 & x<=1, 3/4,
  ifelse( x>=2 & x<=3, 1/4, 0 ))
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-5,5)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=eq, geom="step")
```

Comment: I figured the problem would be something like this. Why does your code work for vectors, while mine doesn't? 

While plotting, I notice the vertical edges are not as perfectly vertical as is expected from a discrete function. What can I do about that?

Comment: `if` works with a single boolean, while `ifelse` works with a vector of booleans. Similarly, `&&` produces a single boolean, while `&` produces a vector of booleans. I have edited my answer to plot the function as a step (or "staircase") function.

Comment: @Gerrit: plots draw lines from one data point to the next.  If you want "true vertical," you'll have to add fake data.  For example, if your two points at the cliff edge were { (5,1) , (6,3) }, you'd create the pseudopoint (6,1) .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is another place where either `switch` could be used to great effect, or something along the lines of
  
    `ysteps <- c(.75,.25,0)

    xsteps <- c(1,2,3)

    y  <- ysteps[which(x >= xsteps)]`

Please feel free to edit this so it's correct -- my brain is slow and I don't have R available right now.